# How to carry on In-App Purchase throughout whole app? (Remove ads from MULTIPLE views)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, iad, restore

I have written my code for an In-App Purchase to remove ads and it works flawlessly, except, it only works on the view controller where I removed my ads from. I want it to carry over throughout my whole app. How would I do that?

Better understanding :

I have Ads on a few view controllers in my app. I have a Information view controller where you can purchase the removal of ads. The thing is : it does't carry over to my other views, as if I go back to the menu view controller. Also, when I go back into the Information view, it still has the ad until I restore from purchases. I don't want the users to continuously restore purchases. How do get this to work?

Comment: Not very clear from your question.  Normally, after you verified a purchase you stored a flag in NSUserDefault or keychain.  And create a helper that will return the status of iap every where you need to know.

Answer (score 3):

As @user523234 mentioned in the comments, you should be using a `NSUserDefault` to store a value that corresponds to the purchase of your IAP.

In this example we use `NSUserDefaults` to check if a key, `removeAds`, is true or false, `YES` or `NO`. The `if` statement will always be true until you set your key to `YES`. For more information on `NSUserDefaults` please refer to  [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

```
// Create this globally
NSUserDefaults *defaults;

// Setup your NSUserDefaults in your viewDidLoad for example
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Check If IAP Has Been Purchased
if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"removeAds"]) {
    // NOT purchased
}

// Upon the successful purchase of your IAP you set the key to YES
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"removeAds"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // Save your changes
```

Comment: Sweet, think I can get that in Swift? I don't know Objective C.

Comment: You should learn Objective-C syntax so you can translate snippets into Swift when necessary. It's a vital skill and is very easy to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Storm's answer is correct. Below is the Swift equivalent:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if !defaults.boolForKey("removeAds") {
    // Not Purchased.
}

// Upon the successful purchase of your IAP, you set the key to true.
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAds")

// Save your changes.
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

I would recommend touching up on Objective-C syntax so you can translate things like this yourself in the future. It's fairly simple, Amit. Mark Daniel's answer as correct.

Comment: Not quite understand this. Where do I put this code, in every view controller I have ads?

Comment: Technically you don't need to call synchronize() unless you can't wait (e.g. you're about to exit or want to reload what's on disk). The system will call it periodically.

Comment: This is actually what I was referring to when I was talking about OOP on Twitter. Having the same code in multiple places is very bad practice and can cause a boat load of problems.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that @DamonJones! Thanks for sharing that. :)

Comment: As @user523234 mentioned on the original question, you should create a helper class out of this so you can just call a helper method to access the snippet.