# Permanently Removing AdMob Ads, Swift 3

Tags: swift, admob

I have ads in my app (provided by admob). These are banners and interstitials. I have used a library to implement them easily. This is called SwiftyAds.

There is a line of code that you can use to remove ads after an in-app purchase

```
SwiftyAds.shared.isRemoved = true
```

This works great after my purchase but when the app is closed, the ads come back. If any one can give me the code to save this boolean that would be amazing. I have heard keychain is better for this sort of thing but anything would be great help. Thanks

Comment: Use `UserDefaults`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31798056/2108547

Answer (score 1):

No, KeyChain is not made to store values like this. You should use UserDefaults to do that. For more information about it, visit documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) and skim for `Bool`.

Simply do: `UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "adsPurchased")` to set the value

And to get the value, use: `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "adsPurchased")`

Now you can do the check. And if user uninstalls the application and re-downloads it, you should have something like "restore purchase" which then checks if user have already purchased it. If it is true, then you can set the bool value to true again.

Comment: Hi, just added UserDefaults.standard.set but the ads still appear when the app is closed. Any ideas why?